# Spring Boot Bucket4j and Hazelcast not working with multiple Pods in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I have set up Bucket4j in my Spring Boot service using the reference [document](https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/08/rate-limit-bucket4j.html#rate-limit-in-a-cluster) .
My App is working fine with single pod deployment . But if I want to scale my application and achieve rate limiting for the complete cluster , I am not able to do so.
Kubernetes Pod is showing error

```
2022-01-05 05:53:29.967  WARN 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] .h.i.s.t.TcpServerConnectionErrorHandler : [11.16.108.90]:5701 [dev] [5.0.2] Removing connection to endpoint [11.16.92.92]:8080 Cause => java.io.EOFException {Remote socket closed!}, Error-Count: 7
2022-01-05 05:53:32.659  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.walmart.orchestrator.HeartBeatHandler  : Heartbeat OK
2022-01-05 05:53:35.662  INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection     : [11.16.108.90]:5701 [dev] [5.0.2] Connection[id=12, /11.16.108.90:54289->/11.16.108.90:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[11.16.108.90]:8080, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
2022-01-05 05:53:35.663  WARN 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] .h.i.s.t.TcpServerConnectionErrorHandler : [11.16.108.90]:5701 [dev] [5.0.2] Removing connection to endpoint [11.16.108.90]:8080 Cause => java.io.EOFException {Remote socket closed!}, Error-Count: 5
```

**References**

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-hazelcast-4</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Config.java

```
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;

@Bean
public Config getConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName(Constants.HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME);
        return config;
    }
```

Bucket Initialisation

```
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.map.IMap;
import io.github.bucket4j.Bandwidth;
import io.github.bucket4j.Bucket;
import io.github.bucket4j.Bucket4j;
import io.github.bucket4j.ConsumptionProbe;
import io.github.bucket4j.Refill;
import io.github.bucket4j.grid.GridBucketState;
import io.github.bucket4j.grid.RecoveryStrategy;
import io.github.bucket4j.grid.hazelcast.Hazelcast;


 Bandwidth limit = Bandwidth.classic(bucketSize, Refill.greedy(bucketSize, Duration.ofMinutes(durationInMin)));
        IMap<String, GridBucketState> map = hzInstance.getMap(Constants.HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME);
        this.bucket = Bucket4j.extension(Hazelcast.class).builder().addLimit(limit)
                .build(map, HANDLER_KEY, RecoveryStrategy.RECONSTRUCT);
```

I want to deploy my service on kubernetes with multiple Pods . Can somebody help me here.

**EDIT**

Adding .yml file for reference. I have not added anything related to hazelcast here.

kitt.yml

```
setup:
  ignoreGitEvents: false
  releaseRefs: ["master","dev"]
  featureFlagMap:
    useFullLooperContent: true     
    buildWhenStageRefMatches: true


owner:
  group: my-namespace
  roles:
    namespaceUsers:
      - my-namespace

alerts:
  slackChannel:
    - my-channel

notify:
  slack:
    channelName: my-channel

profiles:
  - springboot-web
  - default-dev

build:
  skip: false
  artifact: orchestrator
  looper:
    looperFile: looper.yml
    enableDockerNoCache: true
    enableDockerClean: true
  docker:
    app:
      dockerFile: Dockerfile
      buildArgs:
        artifactPath: ./target
        artifactName: orchestrator
        mvnGoals: "clean install -DskipTests"


deploy:
  skip: false
  gslb:
    lbRoutings:
      dev:
          cname: url-1
      stage:
          cname: url-2
  namespace: my-namespace
  releaseType:
    strategy: normal
    rollbackOnError: false
    waitForReady: true
    deployTimeout: 800
  helm:
    values:
      min:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 2G
      max:
        cpu: 4
        memory: 6G
      livenessProbe:
        enabled: "true"
        wait: 120
        path: "/api/live"
      readinessProbe:
        enabled: "true"
        wait: 120
        path: "/api/heartbeat"
      networking:
        pathPrefix: /
        externalPort: "8080"
        internalPort: "8080"

  stages:
    - name: dev
      target:
        - cluster_id: [********]
      refEventFilters:
        - refs: ["dev"]
          events: [onPush]
      helm:
        values:
          scaling:
            enabled: false
            cpuPercent: 80
            max: 1
            min: 1
          env:
            JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: >-
              -Druntime.context.system.property.override.enabled=true
              -Druntime.context.cloud=stg-cdc2
              -Druntime.context.environmentType=stg
              -Druntime.context.appName=frcst-app
```

looper.yml

```
inherit: job:///strati/kitt/kitt-build-assets:looper/base.yml

tools:
  jdk: 1.8
  maven: 3.6.0

cache:
  - name: kitt-maven-cache
    configs:
      - type: maven

envs:
  global:
    variables:
      rootDir: .

scheduling: concurrent


flows:
  default:
    - echo "Running stateless-k8s maven build... but no flow was specified.  Choose one or more of runsonar, buildMvn, buildDocker."

  build:
    try:
      - exposeVars(concEffectivePipeline.yml)
      - var(artifact=${concEffectivePipeline.build.artifact})
      - var(version=${concEffectivePipeline.build.version})
      - var(slackChannelName=${concEffectivePipeline.notify.slack.channelName})
      - call: switchGitBranch(commitEvent=${concEffectivePipeline.build.commitEvent})
      - withcache('kitt-maven-cache'):
          - call: buildMvnFinal(pipeline=${concEffectivePipeline})
      - call: buildDocker(pipeline=${concEffectivePipeline})
    finally:
      - hygieia.publishBuild()

  runsonar:
    - sonar("Sonar"):
        - shell(name sonar): mvn -e -V -B -fae $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL
        - hygieia.publishSonar()

  buildMvnSetup:
    - echo "Performing maven build steps.."
    - echo "testing pwd"
    - var(mavenFlow):
        - echo ${pipeline.build.commitEvent.flow}
    - var(snapshotSuffix):
        - if: |
            %{mavenFlow!="main"}
          then:
            - echo "-SNAPSHOT"
          else:
            - echo ""
    - var(mavenOverrideVersionSet):
        - if: ${pipeline.setup.featureFlagMap.mavenOverrideVersionSet}
          then:
            - echo "${pipeline.setup.featureFlagMap.mavenOverrideVersionSet}"
          else:
            - echo "false"

    - var(mavenGoals):
        - if: ${pipeline.build.docker.app.buildArgs.mvnGoals}
          then:
            - echo ${pipeline.build.docker.app.buildArgs.mvnGoals}
          else:
            - echo "clean install"
    - if: |
        %{mavenOverrideVersionSet=="false"}
      then:
        - shell(name Setting release version to ${version}${snapshotSuffix}): mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${version}${snapshotSuffix}
  buildMvnFinal:
    - dir($rootDir):
        - call: buildMvnSetup(pipeline=${concEffectivePipeline})
        - shell(name Maven build): mvn -B ${pipeline.build.docker.app.buildArgs.mvnGoals}
```

dockerFile

```
FROM docker.prod.walmart.com/strati/zulu:11-jdk-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

#Non Root User Configuration
RUN addgroup -S -g 10001 appGrp \
    && adduser -S -D -u 10000 -s /sbin/nologin -h /opt/app/ -G appGrp app\
    && chown -R 10000:10001 /opt/app

USER 10000

WORKDIR /opt/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-jar",  "/opt/app/app.jar"]
```

**Pod Deployment Json**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: orchestrator
  namespace: aex-aims-orchestrator
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/aex-aims-orchestrator/deployments/orchestrator
  uid: 9c53ec70-47dc-4692-b400-28bf2dac32a8
  resourceVersion: '199583614'
  generation: 55
  creationTimestamp: '2022-01-03T09:35:07Z'
  labels:
    app: orchestrator
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kitt
    app.kubernetes.io/name: orchestrator
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.68
    chart: wce-webapp-basic-0.2.120
    forceApply: L6EYZ
    kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack: aex-aims-orchestrator
    mls-cluster: wcnp
    mls-index: wcnp_aex-aims-orchestrator
    strati.tlsmode: DISABLE
    version: v1
  annotations:
    app.kubernetes.io/scm-url: 'https://gecgithub01.walmart.com/LabsSmartForecasting/sparrow'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '19'
    kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack-ts: slack-1641993317.001300
    sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionPrefixes: 'http.{pod_ip}_'
    sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionSuffixes: >-
      upstream_rq_1xx,upstream_rq_2xx,upstream_rq_3xx,upstream_rq_4xx,upstream_rq_5xx,upstream_rq_time,upstream_cx_tx_bytes_total,upstream_cx_rx_bytes_total,upstream_cx_total,upstream_cx_active,downstream_rq_time,downstream_cx_http1_active,downstream_cx_http2_active
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: '15020,8200'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-01-03T09:35:07Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/scm-url': {}
            'f:kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack-ts': {}
            'f:sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionPrefixes': {}
            'f:sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionSuffixes': {}
            'f:traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/version': {}
            'f:chart': {}
            'f:forceApply': {}
            'f:kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack': {}
            'f:mls-cluster': {}
            'f:mls-index': {}
            'f:strati.tlsmode': {}
            'f:version': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:progressDeadlineSeconds': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:revisionHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:selector':
            'f:matchLabels':
              .: {}
              'f:app': {}
              'f:version': {}
          'f:strategy':
            'f:rollingUpdate':
              .: {}
              'f:maxSurge': {}
              'f:maxUnavailable': {}
            'f:type': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:annotations':
                .: {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/scm-url': {}
                'f:kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack-ts': {}
                'f:sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionPrefixes': {}
                'f:sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionSuffixes': {}
                'f:traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts': {}
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/version': {}
                'f:forceApply': {}
                'f:kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack': {}
                'f:mls-cluster': {}
                'f:mls-index': {}
                'f:strati.tlsmode': {}
                'f:version': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"orchestrator"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:env':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"name":"JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                  'f:image': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:realdinessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:httpGet':
                      .: {}
                      'f:httpHeaders': {}
                      'f:path': {}
                      'f:port': {}
                      'f:scheme': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:resources':
                    .: {}
                    'f:limits':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:ephemeral-storage': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                    'f:requests':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:ephemeral-storage': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                  'f:securityContext':
                    .: {}
                    'f:allowPrivilegeEscalation': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:runAsNonRoot': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
              'f:topologySpreadConstraints':
                .: {}
                'k:{"topologyKey":"failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone","whenUnsatisfiable":"ScheduleAnyway"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:labelSelector':
                    .: {}
                    'f:matchLabels':
                      .: {}
                      'f:app': {}
                  'f:maxSkew': {}
                  'f:topologyKey': {}
                  'f:whenUnsatisfiable': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-01-12T13:23:38Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:availableReplicas': {}
          'f:conditions':
            .: {}
            'k:{"type":"Available"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Progressing"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:readyReplicas': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:updatedReplicas': {}
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orchestrator
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: orchestrator
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kitt
        app.kubernetes.io/name: orchestrator
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.68
        forceApply: CE3pW
        kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack: aex-aims-orchestrator
        mls-cluster: wcnp
        mls-index: wcnp_aex-aims-orchestrator
        strati.tlsmode: DISABLE
        version: v1
      annotations:
        app.kubernetes.io/scm-url: 'https://gecgithub01.walmart.com/LabsSmartForecasting/sparrow'
        kitt.wcnp.io/notify-slack-ts: slack-1641993317.001300
        sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionPrefixes: 'http.{pod_ip}_'
        sidecar.istio.io/statsInclusionSuffixes: >-
          upstream_rq_1xx,upstream_rq_2xx,upstream_rq_3xx,upstream_rq_4xx,upstream_rq_5xx,upstream_rq_time,upstream_cx_tx_bytes_total,upstream_cx_rx_bytes_total,upstream_cx_total,upstream_cx_active,downstream_rq_time,downstream_cx_http1_active,downstream_cx_http2_active
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: '15020,8200'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: orchestrator
          image: 'docker.prod.walmart.com/labssmartforecasting/sparrow:0.0.68'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
              value: >-
                -Druntime.context.system.property.override.enabled=true
                -Druntime.context.cloud=stg-cdc2
                -Druntime.context.environmentType=stg
                -Druntime.context.appName=frcst-app
            - name: LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS
              value: 'true'
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '4'
              ephemeral-storage: 1500M
              memory: 6G
            requests:
              cpu: '1'
              ephemeral-storage: 1G
              memory: 2G
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: orchestrator
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 55
  replicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 2
  readyReplicas: 2
  availableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-01-12T13:16:10Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-01-06T05:09:38Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet "orchestrator-6c7c69cd9b" has successfully progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-01-12T13:23:38Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-01-12T13:23:38Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
```

Comment: It looks as if you have nodes with different Hazelcast versions in your cluster. What's your architecture?

Comment: @Nicolas I have a single deployment in kubernetes. The code base for all the pods is same . The dependencies in pom related to hazelcast are shared above . Can u help me debug the problem ?

Comment: I have not added quorum size anywhere in the config . What is the default quorum size ? How do I update the quorum size in my current implementation ?

Comment: Please update your initial question with the exact Kubernetes manifest. Also, do you have the hazelcast-kubernetes-plugin in your dependencies list? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes

Comment: @Nicolas updated the initial question. As per the link provided by you DEPRECATED: hazelcast-kubernetes plugin has been merged with hazelcast!
Since version 5.0 hazelcast includes hazelcast-kubernetes and does not require additional dependency. I have hazelcast 5.0 dependency

Comment: Oops, you're correct. Now I see you've added your build YAML files, but not the Kubernetes manifests, which are relevant.

Comment: @Nicolas Added deployment resource. Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Now, what version of hazelcast-spring are you using in your XML snippet are you using?

Comment: @Nicolas I have removed the hazelcast-spring dependency from my pom.xml as it was not required . I have updated the XML in the question above .

FYI: I have tried running the cluster on my local system and hazelcast is running fine with this config and creating a cluster successfully. I think the issue is that I am not able to expose my pods IP's to each other while deploying to kubernetes . Maybe I have to follow this document https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-set-up-your-own-on-premises-hazelcast-on-kubernetes/

Comment: I think this is the most up-to-date guide: https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-embedded/